# Unable to Run unitest cases in windows with ant

Tags: java, ant

Unable to Run unitest cases in windows with ant, failing with below error

> F:\work\svnroot\EBH-1051\applications\ebates\unittest\build.xml:53: Process 
>      fork failed.
>           at org.testng.TestNGAntTask.executeAsForked(TestNGAntTask.java:837)
>           .....
>
> "F:\work\svnroot\external\lib\installations\jdk1.8\windows\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)

the root cause for my problem is the classpath is very huge. I need a solution without touching classpath jars.

Please help on this.

Thanks,
Syamala.

Comment: Have you considered going through other threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749010/maven-and-ant-cant-run-java-createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extensio)

Comment: Can run show the output by running the ant script in debug mode? By the way as the error message is clear right?